# How to override javascript in customize-controls.js

Tags: theme-customizer

Is there a way to override a javascript section of wordpress core code in the customize-controls.js file? Like is there a way to do a search/filter with php and tell wordpress to replace with something with empty or "". I think probably not possible so I will need to edit the javascript myself.

So that file is considered "old"? In customize-controls.js how frequently is the code changed in new versions? If I make my own fix I don't want to keep applying a new fix each time I upgrade.

Some of the code for setting padding is bad code and should not be in the javascript to begin with and it causes bugs. So I want to not use the part that does not function well.

Comment: Older WordPress JavaScript is generally not filterable that way. Editing core files is _strongly_ discouraged (and probably wouldn’t work because you’d need to edit the minified version).  What problem are you hoping to solve by doing this?

Comment: So that file is considered "old"? In customize-controls.js how frequently is the code changed in new versions? If I make my own fix I don't want to keep applying a new fix each time I upgrade.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if the developers make a change to it, all WordPress files are replaced during an upgrade so you would always need to keep applying the fix. That’s one reason why it’s highly discouraged. Why do you need to modify it?